# BCP How to specify an empty field_terminator

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm new with BCP on SQL Server, I've checked on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx to know how to use the BCP parameters.
The parameter for field_terminator is -t, if i want to put a comma between each field i put '-t ,', that's OK.

But how to specify an empty 'space' between fields?

I have already tried to not put the `-t` parameter, but by default it's a TAB...

EDIT: sorry, I wasn't precise enough; it's for BCP EXPORT with a sql query like

```
'BCP "select * from ##OutputTable' + '" queryout \\server\filename_' 
   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @CurrentID) + '.upl -t , -w -T -S' + @InstanceName
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation doesn't offer much detail on this. BCP actually needs the hex representation (`0x20`) for space delimited logs. This worked for me in the cmd line:

```
bcp webLogs.dbo.iisLogs IN C:\temp\logs\ex170112.log -c -t0x20 -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -T
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the bulk insert answer, you should be able to use `-t' '` to specify a space as the field terminator.

```
'BCP "select * from ##OutputTable' + '" queryout \\server\filename_' 
   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @CurrentID) + '.upl -t' ' -w -T -S' + @InstanceName
```

Comment: this doesn't works, and i'd like to have no space, nothing between fields even a ' ', just a '' :) thx

Comment: @Mentezza have you tried `-t''`?  Just two single quotes (or two double quotes) with no space between?

Answer (score 0):

When I used the \0 terminator (null terminator) the text file I set as output had a space between each column value. Maybe this is the one you need to use.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below example, but using a space ' ' instead of the comma.

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
BULK INSERT myDepartment FROM 'C:\myDepartment-c-t.txt'
   WITH (
      DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```